# wordpress Ajax success doesn't return the value

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, ajax, rest-api

I have created a plugin where I am recieving the data via rest url and I am getting the correct output when I use `var_dump($final_price_return);` and no return in success call. PHP code that returns the value:

```
function handle_query($data) {
    // Handle the form data that is posted
    // Get all parameters from form
    $output = $data->get_params();

    // Check if nonce is valid, if not, respond back with error
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($output['_wpnonce'], 'wp_rest')) {
        return new WP_Rest_Response('Oops - Invalid request', 422);
    }

    // done calculations here - skipped that code for now

    var_dump($final_price_return);
    return new WP_REST_Response($final_price_return, 200);
}
```

JQuery Code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $('#calx').on('click', function (e) {
          $('#msform').validate({
            rules: {
              // simple rule, converted to {required:true}
              service: 'required',
              square_feet: 'required',
            },
            messages: {
              service: 'Please select service',
              square_feet: 'Please select your square feet area',
            },
            submitHandler: function () {
              var formData = $('#msform').serialize()
              jQuery.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo get_rest_url(null, 'bohio/v1/submit'); ?>",
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                success: function (res) {
                  console.log(res)
                  $('#total_amount').html(res)
                  $('#totalbox').removeClass('d-none')
                  $('#email_form').removeClass('d-none')
                },
              })
            },
          })
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this... ...rather than returning the value, send a JSON success message.

```
$response = new WP_REST_Response($final_price_return, 200);
wp_send_json_success( $response );
wp_die();  
//you have to end the process, so if you're getting just a 0 returned in your JS success, it's because of this.
```

Then, in your JS/jQuery:

```
success: function (success, data) {
  var res = success.data;
  console.log(res)
  $('#total_amount').html(res)
  $('#totalbox').removeClass('d-none')
  $('#email_form').removeClass('d-none')
},
```

It may even just be that your lack of `wp_die()` or lack of `exit()` at the end of your AJAX callback is the issue.